# Reinitializaing C3P0 Connection to DB After Play recompile

Tags: jdbc, playframework, c3p0

I've been having problems recreating my C3P0 connection after play framework recompiles my code; I have to manually stop the server and restart.  At first I thought it was because I couldn't create 2 datasources to the same DB instance, however destroying the datasource doesn't help, and I tried initializing my CP30 datasource twice in a row still worked.

Here's my initialization code:

```
cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass(m_driverClass);
cpds.setUser(m_userName);
cpds.setPassword(m_password);

cpds.setMinPoolSize(5);
cpds.setAcquireIncrement(5);
cpds.setMaxPoolSize(20);

cpds.setJdbcUrl(m_jdbcUrl);
checkIfDBExists();              
cpds.setJdbcUrl(m_jdbcUrl + ";databaseName=" + m_dbName);
```

and here's my destroy code:

```
 if (cpds != null) {
    cpds.resetPoolManager();
    cpds.close();
    DataSources.destroy(cpds);
}
```

My code just calls initialize, and it tries to destroy() in the initialize.  It also checks whether the DB has been initialized or not using the metadata:

```
try {
    conn = getConnection();
    resultSet = conn.getMetaData().getCatalogs();
    conn.commit();
} finally {
    if (conn != null) conn.close();
}
```

This getConnection() (simply calls cpds.getConnection()) gets stuck when it restarts and the error message says it can't get the connection from the underlying database.

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: hi... why would you destroy() when you initialize? in any case, the most obvious question is when Play recompiles and redeploys, is there some hook from which you can cleanup and restart resources (something analogous to a ServletContextListener). for example, is your cleanup code (which is a bit overdone) propery called when tearing down for redeploy?

Comment: I'm only calling destroy() in case the cpds was still alive for whatever reason, it doesn't really matter if I call it or not; it still gets stuck.  I do call destroy when it hits the shut-down hook before the redeploy, it still doesn't stop the getConnection() from stalling out.